# Reduce processing time for re.sub() in a nested loop

Tags: python, regex, recursion, preprocessor, mutual-recursion

I am preprocessing a set of files where one file is included in another file with an include tag like shown below:

file A

```
include file B
include file C
 contents of file A
include file D
 contents of file A
```

Here i need to replace the include tags with contents of each of the respective files. Just like what a compiler does. I have two functions for that

```
    def parseContent(self, rdbFilePath, content):
        finalContent = self.removeComments(content)
        includeFileSearch = re.compile(r'(?P<tag>(\s)*include+(\s*)\"(\s*)(?P<file>[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_/]*)\")')
        for includes in includeFileSearch.finditer(finalContent):
            finalContent = re.sub(includes.group('tag'),self.parseIncludes(rdbFilePath, includes.group('file')), finalContent)
        return finalContent

    def parseIncludes(self, rdbFilePath, file):
        path = rdbFilePath + "/" + file
        f = open(path)
        pathDir = os.path.dirname(path)
        includedFileContent = self.parseContent(pathDir, f.read())
        return includedFileContent
```

As you can see, functions `parseContent` and `parseIncludes` is called in each other recursively to replace all the include tags in every file. The logic works fine. But it takes a bit long time to execute. Is there any better way to do the same with lesser execution time?

Comment: What do you mean by "one file is included in another file with an include tag"?

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @ajinLJA-0184 just like how <stdio.h> contents are included in your code

Comment: I just found this today, but it's missing substitution features: https://github.com/facebook/pyre2/ My thought is that you might be able to work around the substitution. I have no experience with it though, so, I'm not sure if it's appreciably faster, or if it will work well enough for your use case.